# Changing variable value by next element in array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array with some text. One variable is set to first element in the array, how can I set that function can change that variable change value to value from next element in an array?

```
var q= [{qs: 'JR?', id: 1},
{qs: 'DR?', idp: 2}, 
{qs: 'MR ?', idp: 3}, 
{qs: 'SR ?', idp: 4}, 
{qs: 'LR ?', idp: 5} ];
$scope.qes= q[0].qs;
$scope.check= function(){
   $scope.qes = q[0].qs + 1; // something like that
}
```

Comment: JavaScript is a "by-value" language, even though the "value" can be a reference to an object. Because of that, you can edit the content of the object but you can't swap out the object itself in its original location. You just don't have an access to the memory location of the original position in the array.

Comment: keep the index somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not enough clear.

As per your array initially you have 'DR?' in " $scope.check" variable. If you want 'MR?' as the next then do the following

You need to change the current element of the array. Suppose if as default a pointer points the first element of the array then the initial position will be 0. And all you need to do to increment the position value by 1.

```
//first take a pointer set to 0 [as here 0 is default position]

    $scope.pos= 0;
    $scope.check= function(){
       //change position to next 
       $scope.pos=$scope.pos+1;
       $scope.qes = q[$scope.pos].qs;
    }
```